# How do I serve a binary file through rack?

Tags: ruby, file, rack

I think I'm being a bit silly here, but I keep getting errors complaining about the SERVER_NAME key missing from the env hash, and I can't find any substantial documentation on Rack::SendFile..

so- how do I serve up files?

Answer (score 0):

If you're serving large files for download, I'd recommend to let the webserver serve the large data. This way, you don't waste precious resources for running your Rack app just to let the user do a lengthy download.

If you response with a special Header (`X-Sendfile` for Apache, `X-Accel-Redirect` for Nginx), the webserver will use the content of the file given as the body for the response. This way, your Rack app becomes ready for the next request while the webserver takes care of the lengthy process of sending data to the user. You may need to enable this feature for your webserver first.

Comment: Sorry, this does not actually solve your Rack::SendFile problem but still might be an interesting option.